# Reading data from text file and storing to GridGain cache

Tags: file, file-handling, gridgain, ignite

I'm trying to use GridGain In-memory data grid for reading data from a regular .txt file and write it to the cache and vice versa. I could find documents for how to do it with H2 Database, but I couldn't find anything on how to do it with files.

Could someone help me by telling how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean Apache Ignite cache?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Ignite `CacheStore` will work with any persistence implementation, whether it is a database, or a simple file system. All you need to do is implement a few methods on the `CacheStore` API.

Please take a look at this documentation: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistent-store

Comment: Yes, but I don't need JDBC or something for files right? Then how do I do it? Please guide me, I'm confused.

Comment: No, there is no requirement for JDBC or anything else. `CacheStore` interface is a special abstraction that allows you to provide any implementation of the persistence store. Simply implement the interface and provide the implementation in cache configuration as shown in the documentation.